# JavaScript Object giving different values when accessed directly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, javascript-objects

I am using React.js and I'm trying to update the state of my component when the props change. Before I explain the problem, I should mention that I have used both getDerivedStateFromProps and componentDidUpdate, the result is the same. The problem is that when I try to access the value of an element in prop, it differs whether I access the value directly or I use the object itself.

```
let userTickets = nextProps.support.userTickets;
// userTickets[0].messages is different from nextProps.support.userTickets[0].messages
```

below is the whole function code.

```
let userTickets = nextProps.support.userTickets;
console.log(nextProps.support.userTickets); // this contains the correct, updated value
for (let index = 0; index < userTickets.length; index++) {
let userTicket = userTickets[index];
console.log(userTicket); // this contains old incorrect value
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "console.log" is deceptive because it updates the values in the console if it changes; log the stringified version instead to avoid this. Without any context it's difficult to help other than to point you at a possible async issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not directly assign props to variables because it may assign by reference instead of copy. Try this instead:

```
const userTickets = [ ...nextProps.support.userTickets ];
console.log(nextProps.support.userTickets);
userTickets.map(ticket => {
    console.log(ticket);
});
```

Notice the 3 dot assignment of the array, this creates a new array with the values of the array that is "spread"